# Unit test in multi-module gradle spring project

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, gradle, multi-module

I have multi-module project with similar structure as below:

- **core** (*which includes Application Context Configuration*) as a main project includes core-lib
- **core-lib** (which is independent of main project, contains classes for communicate with core (dtos, some logic))

I want to write test in core-lib module but I don't have App Context Config there and I can't run the whole Spring Application.

How to run unit tests in *core-lib* which depends of main *core* project classes (eg. Database configuration bean)?.

Comment: The question begs itself, if the classes in your core-lib are independent, why do they need to run inside a spring context?

Comment: The lib doesn't have dependency to core in gradle config but it use bean classes (by dependency injection mechanism) from core. So it is reason why lib needs compiled core for unit tests. The lib never runs without core.

Comment: If lib never runs without core, then why not just collapse them into a single module and save yourself the headache? It sounds like you have a circular dependency right now but Spring DI is letting you hide that

Comment: I have the lib for communicate other modules in project with core. When i jus collapse lib into single module it wont be possible to compile project (circular dependency - core depends of some module and some module depends of core).

I will expand the whole project structure:
-PROJECT
--core (contains AppContextConfig)
---lib_core
--module1 (depends of lib_core)
---lib_module1
--module2 (depends of lib_core)
---lib_module2